# I have installed IPython, and still "No module named 'IPython'"

Tags: python, installation, ipython

My Python version:`Python 3.8.3`

`python -m pip install IPython`  gives me `Successfully installed IPython-7.18.1`

Still gives me the following error:

```
  from IPython.display import Image
    /usr/bin/python3 "/home/sanyifeju/Desktop/python/ML/decision_trees.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanyifeju/Desktop/python/ML/decision_trees.py", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython.display import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'
```

'
What am I missing?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.1 , not sure if that makes any difference.

if I run `python -m pip install ipython`

I get Requirement already satisfied.

```
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (7.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (49.6.0.post20200814)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3; sys_platform != "win32" in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython) (1.15.0)
```

Comment: Try restarting your kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the problem was that the `python` command was linked to the python2 version:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2*
```

The following commands fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
$ sudo ln -s python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing-

```
python -m pip install ipython
```

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /home/sanyifeju/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (7.18.1)

Comment: If you're using `anaconda`, `ipython` comes preinstalled. Try typing `'jupyter qtconsole'` and see if an `iPython terminal` opens. If so it will tell you that ipython is installed and it will list version number.

Comment: Jupyter QtConsole 4.7.7
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Comment: Are you using anaconda for running the file? Make sure you're using the same path for installation.

Comment: I try to run the whole script from Visual Studio Code

Comment: Can you try running the file using `anaconda prompt`? In anaconda prompt, type `cd 'home/sanyifeju/Desktop/python/ML/'`. Then try `python decision_trees.py`. If it runs successfully, you either need to change the environment for VS Code or install ipython in the current environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222075/discussion-between-shradha-and-sanyifej).